# Woodstain to 'weather-proof' pine?

Tags: staining, weather-resistant

I have some cheap pine shelves that I plan to put outside on the balcony to grow some herbs. To 'weather-proof' it, I've bought some clear woodstain. I decided on wood stain because it was recommended to me by the home center staff. But watching some YouTube videos this morning, someone said wood stain does not provide any protection against the elements. So I'm now wondering if I bought the right stuff.

If it is, I believe a light sand, wood stain, another light sand and a second layer of wood stain, will be sufficient? Do I need anything else?

Comment: This is a good question and you've received a good answer from Solar Mike. I'd suggest some additional reading at [woodworking.se], specifically, look at the [finishing] and [finish-selection] tags. There is a _ton_ of information there about protecting wood from weather. So much so, that if this question would have been posted there, it would have likely been closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

Wood stain is used to color the timber, it may also be designed to offer some protection from sunlight.

However, if the timber is outside in the sun, wind, rain and snow then another protection will be needed. One is varnish and I tend to find the (more expensive) yacht varnish most hardy. But nature is relentless...

Comment: Correct. Wood "stain" is exactly that - it's like pouring grape juice on a white shirt, it leaves a stain. It does nothing to protect the surface.

Comment: Thanks, both. But if thats what it is, why do they sell 'clear' wood stain.That would be like pouring water on a white shirt! Is it an evil plot to get me to waste money?